# Make overfitting tree with maximum depth using ctree

Tags: r, party, ctree

When plotting a `ctree` model from partykit, I understand that it choose a default to prevent overfitting with overgrown trees. This default value sometimes results in an overly simple tree. To use a post-pruning technique I want to make an overfitting tree, potentially full-grown, using ctree and then work on the pruning later. Try many different things but my code is getting an error.

This stack overflow answer on using [all variables to make the tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22443554/r-decision-tree-using-all-the-variables/22595287#22595287) is not what I want. I don't necessarily want all variables, but I want maximum depth for a tree to go as overgrown as possible.

Basically, how to have the tree go as many depths as possible?

See code and output below:

```
treemodel <- ctree(Species ~ ., iris)
plot(treemodel)
```

And I use the Help + documentation from the package but don't see a lot of options to customize this. Promising one is the control parameter, but the documentation isn't very detailed. From searching on other forums, I gave the following a try:

```
treemodel <- ctree(Species ~ ., iris, control=mincriterion)
```

I also tried:

```
treemodel <- ctree(Species ~ ., iris, control="mincriterion")
```

But both code throws an error. The error:

> Error in if (sum(weights) < ctrl$minsplit)
>   return(partynode(as.integer(id))) : argument is of length zero

I am using partykit 1.1-1 and r on mac os.

Comment: Maybe just use `tree` or `rpart` packages to get a fully grown tree.

Comment: is there a reason why you recommend tree or rpart over ctree? i'm following a tutorial and want to stick as much as possible to the tutorial course, but i appreciate the suggestion thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ctree` from `partykit` accepts a `ctree_control` parameter through the `control` argument that you can use to control aspects of the tree fit.

Doing `control=mincriterion` or `control="mincriterion"` is not correct and hence you get an error. `control` expects a list with control parameters, not a character value.

In particular, you want to pass into `ctree_control` the following:

- `mincriterion`: Act as a "regulator" for the depth of the tree,
  smaller values result in larger trees; When mincriterion is 0.8,
  p-value must be smaller than 0.2 in order for a node to split
- `minsplit` and `minbucket`: Set to 0 so the minimum criterion is
  **always** met and thus splitting never stop

From the package's author itself:

> A split is implemented when the criterion exceeds the value given by
>   mincriterion as specified in ctree_control. For example, when
>   mincriterion = 0.95, the p-value must be smaller than 0.05 in order to
>   split this node. This statistical approach ensures that the
>   right-sized tree is grown without additional (post-)pruning or
>   cross-validation

So with that, the final code using `control=ctree_control()`:

```
diab_model <- ctree(diabetes ~ ., diab_train, control = ctree_control(mincriterion=0.005, minsplit=0, minbucket=0))
plot(diab_model)
```

The first line of code creates your decision tree by overriding the defaults, and the second line of code plots the `ctree` object. You'll get a fully grown tree with maximum depth. Experiment with the values of `mincriterion`, `minsplit`, and `minbucket`. They can also be treated as a hyperparameter. Here's the output of `plot(diab_model)`

[image]